# iOS - How can we set notification badge counter using FCM when the app is in background?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I  am trying to set the notification badge counter in my app when the app is in background/terminated?

But I'm not getting any clue how should I set the badge counter .

In foreground it's fine I can update notification badge counter.

Now I tried to use the background service by adding content_availbe key in firebase payload and invoking the following method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
```

But my this method is not invoked although i've included content_available key to 1 in my payload.

Has anyone been able to set the notification badge counter when the app is in background with fcm messages?

**NOTE: ** I am concerned about updating push notification counter from app not from the server. Can we update app badge counter from background execution ??

Any help.

Comment: Did you enable the push notifications background mode ?

Comment: @deadbeef: yeah done from capabilities

Comment: Probably this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256852/1534329) can help you.

Comment: @Martin it's not for FCM , we got two objects notification and data in fcm payload i got no idea where to put badges.

but my concern is i want to update counter from background , is that possible ???