# App Delegate Behaviour when app is in different States

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have some logic within my app delegate on iOS for handling incrementing a push notification badge - but have had intermittent behaviour with this for some users.

The app is registered for background remote notifications.

[image: Visual Studio Settings]

Notifications are received fine when app is in foreground, background or phone is restarted.

A few different scenarios occur:

1. Foreground - notification & badge.
2. Background - notification & badge.
3. App Killed - notification & badge **sometimes**
4. Device Restart - notification & no badge.

My question is - does App Delegate code run when an iOS app is killed by the user (for a period of time -i.e until another app takes up that space in RAM) and does App Delegate code not run at all if the device is restarted?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo

Comment: Also see [Using background tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app).

Comment: Please take a look at this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background/53159748#53159748). It may help you with badge count.