# Show badge number when notification received

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push

When notification reach the application, there is no action on badge number. I set background mode on Capabilities.

And there is another problem. This metod does not invoke when app is background mode.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Push notification received2: \(userInfo)")
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
}
```

PS: UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber is not answer. I know that. The problem is even the push notification received by application, the badge number does not update.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background
follow this link please

Comment: Badge number which show on app icon is manage directly by OS, if notification payload send badge number correclty it shows automatically.

Answer (score 3):

> APNS doesn't support increment operations for badges. each push notification generated should be setting what the current value should be.

so we need to have a service/server somewhere keeping track of what badges should be for each of your users

for example add the one key of `badge` in your payload, get the count of your badge and increment the count followed by the example.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    var currentBadgeNumber: Int = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber
    currentBadgeNumber += Int(userInfo["badge"] as? String ?? "0")!
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = currentBadgeNumber
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
}
```

for example payload, see the [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background) in SO.

Note : didReceiveRemoteNotification is deprecated from iOS10+ onwards, see this for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382852/didreceiveremotenotification-not-called-ios-10/39383027#39383027)

Comment: I use willPresent method now. But It does not invoke when app is on background.

Comment: @tersintersi- sorry for delay reply, if your app is background then this method will be called. `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {`