# iOS: didReceiveRemoteNotification is not being called when the app is in background

Tags: swift, aps

Despite having "remote notification" in background modes, the app does not seem to do anything when the app is in the background. All I want to do is updating the badge number when the app is closed or terminated (like what Twitter app does).

```
func application( _ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 99 // just to test
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

Background Mode settings:
[image]

When the app is in foreground it updates the badge, this is the payload:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "badge": 4,
    "content-available": 1,
    "mutable-content": 0
  }
}
```

But when it's in background it does nothing. Should it not update the badge?

Comment: This might or might not be relevant: your code is wrong, because you are not calling the `completionHandler`.

Comment: In the actual code I do call it, I just didn't put it here. it's either `completionHandler(.newData)` or with `.noData` or `.failed`

Comment: OK so does anything happen at all? Does the badge change to `4`?

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background. You either pass `badge` in `aps` or set it in code, but not both.

Comment: No nothing happens, no matter if I have or have not `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber`, the badge number won't change.